# MongoDB C# driver class has an other name than the collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am working with a MongoDB but I my class has another name then my collection.

```
[DataObject]
[BsonDiscriminator("TES_SuperHero")]
public class SuperHero
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Powers")]
    public IList<HeroPowers> SuperPowers { get; set; }
}
```

Then I want to get the Collection with

```
private IMongoCollection<SuperHero> _superHeros = _MongoClient.GetDatabase().GetCollection<SuperHero>(nameof(SuperHero));
```

The only problem is that I can't seem to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass in the database name in to the `GetDatabase` method

```
_superHeros = _MongoClient.GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<SuperHero>(nameof(SuperHero));
```

Name is not optional, See - http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClient_GetDatabase.htm